# AMP-Stories and Google Analytics not tracking event triggers

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, amp-html, amp-story

I have made a few triggers to track analytics inside AMP-stories with google analytics based on the following articles/documentations:

1. https://samuelschmitt.com/google-amp-stories/
2. https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/amp-story-analytics.md
3. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=viewing+amp-stories+analytics+in+google+analytics#kpvalbx=_PAhIXd_2IdqU8gLpmJWYCg10
4. https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/configure-analytics/analytics-vendors/

Here is the script in the :

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

And here is what is in the :

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="storiesanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{

    "vars": {
    "account": "UA-MYNUMBER-X"
  },
    "triggers": {
        "storyPageVisible": {
          "on": "story-page-visible",
          "request": "event"
        },
        "StoryBookendEnter": {
            "on": "story-bookend-enter",
            "request": "event"
        },
        "StoryView": {
          "on": "visible",
          "request": "pageview"
        },
        "Bookend Enter": {
          "on": "story-bookend-exit",
          "request": "event"
        },

    }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

**Note**:
For an AMP-story to be valid AMP there should only be ONE child element in it. That's why I have included the  inside the  opening tag. This validates the page as an AMP page.

## Problem:

While I can see myself being active in Google Analytics Real Time, the events are not being logged. I currently have a Total Events of 0.
Page views do work but the triggers don't seem to.

I can't seem to find whats going wrong.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @vijayscode nope I haven't!